# Interaction between two never ending python scripts

Tags: python, apache-kafka, mqtt, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I have a mqtt broker to which I have subscribed and continuously recieving data.

code

```
# broker.py

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received ")
    # do some calculations on the data recieved.
    target_variable  = #stored after the calculations.

client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback

print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address, port=port,) #connect to broker
client.subscribe("topic")
client.loop_forever() #stop the loop
```

so when i run this python script ,it is a forever process, continuously updating the target variable. I want to use this target variable in a different script.

code

```
# main.py

import schedule
from broker.py import target_variable


def job():
    # use target_variable and perform some taks
    print(target_variable)

schedule.every(60).seconds.do(job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

This is also a forever process and runs the job for every 60 seconds. I want to use the target_variable from broker.py  in the main.py.

I am not able to run these two things in a single script, if I have seperate scripts and try to load broker.py in main.py , broker.py is only getting executing and doesnot get end.

Can someone help me in how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly make those as functions and launch them as deamon threads in single script so that it will be running forever until you stop the script.
An example would be:

```py
def myfunc1(i):
    # any job you want to do
    pass
def myfunc2():
    # any job you want to do
    pass

t1 = Thread(target=myfunc1, args=(,))
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=myfunc2, args=(,))
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()
```